# There isn't really an isolated system so why sometimes we consider a system to be isolated?

Tags: approximations

In real life, there's nothing to be called an isolated system then why at some applications do we assign isolated systems?

Comment: There are many situations where a system is approximately isolated i.e. the perturbations from external sources are small compared to the behaviour we are studying. For example the Solar System is [currently](http://www.universetoday.com/119038/a-star-passed-through-the-solar-system-just-70000-years-ago/) approximately an isolated system if we're studying its dynamics.

Comment: Because it makes the physics easier, and many systems are, as @JohnRennie points out, isolated enough that it doesn't make a measurable difference in the answer. Do you wake up in the morning complaining about how much heavier the Andromeda galaxy is making you feel?

Answer (score 2):

Considering a dynamical system isolated is a simplifying assumption such as assuming there is no friction, ignoring quantum effects and relativity or similar. In fact with any real system we have to make all sorts of assumptions to make them any treatable.

As with any assumption, we can use the assumption of isolation as long as we can still obtain useful results with it. Some examples:

- The heart is clearly not an isolated system. We cannot predict the phase of the heartbeat on time scales of an hour. Nontheless, simulating it as an isolated system (and with tons of further assumptions), we can gain insights on its inner workings, understand how malfunctions like fibrillation occur and learn something about treating them.
- The weather is clearly not an isolated system and even if we perfectly knew its state and simulated its internal dynamics, we could not make long-term predictions due to the butterfly effect. Still, we can make useful short-term predictions.
- Every working piece of technology is built with the assumption of isolated systems, be it made for the piece itself, the piece and its application or certain parts of the piece. Still this assumption was sufficient to predict the piece’s behaviour sufficiently to make it, well, a working piece of technology.